# Variety of mindmapping, with the ability to click a node and see all interconnected nodes

Tags: mind-mapping

I'm looking for a piece of (preferably Windows) software where one can create a mindmap-like chart which can be navigated by clicking on a node.

Example: topic a is connected to topic b, and topic b is connected to topics c, d, and e. If you were to click on topic b, it'd center on topic b and show topics a, c, d, and e in a radial fashion around it, then if you were to click on topic d, it'd show topic b as being connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to this that I know of is [TheBrain](http://thebrain.com) software. 
In response to a comment, here is a little more information. A little, because I've only started messing with the demo. From what I've seen so far, it seems better suited to handling large amounts of connected nodes/information than a mind mapping or concept map. As per the original question, the question itself describes the behavior of TheBrain's "Plex" feature which makes navigation through nodes in a network more manageable than a typical mind mapping application. You have to try it or visit jerrysbrain.com to see a web based example of same. It is better experienced than explained in words. Being an org-mode user myself, I am experimenting with org-brain, which is based on TheBrain, in the hopes that I can get many of the benefits of mindmapping inside org-mode. But that is only a helpful aside for the questioner to consider.

Comment: This looks like a link only answer ...

Answer (score 1):

After looking on and off for years for a good Mind Mapping software, I stumbled on [Thinkcomposer](http://www.thinkcomposer.com/) fairly recently, and it had most everything I was looking for.  I know that you can expand and collapse nodes as well as stacking them, both features I was looking for at the time.

Comment: Is that "expand/collapse ALL", or only the node surrounding the one clicked, as the OP asks?

Comment: Looks like "compositional levels" might help?  http://www.thinkcomposer.com/Content/features/ThinkComposer-MultiLevel.jpg